# how post date.time value to model controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I don't know how to pass `DateTime` value to my model from `Html.BeginForm`.
I don't want to use calender.
Can I use hidden field to pass it to model?

```
public partial class gpAdmin
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime registerDate { get; set; }

    }
```

and view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Name")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)
            </div>
           ......
    }
```

and register controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(gpAdmin admin)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         ds.gpAdmin.Add(admin);
         ds.SaveChanges();
     }
     return view();
}
```

What should I do for the `registerDate` field, which is a `DateTime` type?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.registerDate)` would be fine.

Comment: Or `@Html.HidenFor(a => a.registerDate)` of you want a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `@Html.EditorFor(a=>a.registerDate).`

You may also consider adding attributes to the field

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime registerDate { get; set; }
```

If you want that to be hidden use `@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.registerDate)`

But if you have to use `@Html.HiddenFor` I recommend not using it at all and initializing default date in the model constructor itself.. use the following code

```
public partial class gpAdmin
{
    public gpAdmin()
    {
        registerDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime registerDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did your solution but not working still registerdate field in sql database is empty!!!

Comment: Are you using HiddenFor or EditorFor ?

Comment: Edited the answer. If you have to use HiddenFor, initialize the date in the model constructor.